# What is the best way to get superglue off a Corian countertop?

Tags: cleaning, kitchen-counters

My kids and I have spilled superglue onto a Corian countertop in our kitchen, I've heard you can buff out scratches and such from these, but I'd rather avoid scraping and buffing if possible.  Is there another way to get superglue off these?

--UPDATE
The debonder didn't work, so maybe not CA based glue, will try the razor blade, but has to be when the wife is away...

Comment: I'm in the same pickle, wondering what method worked?

Comment: I decided the best policy was to leave it alone as causing any more damage would get me in more trouble.

Comment: I did finally end up using a butter knife to scrape it away. This worked ok, just don't dig in to hard and the corian is fine. Takes some time though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acetone-based nail polish remover and an old dinner knife worked very well. Pour acetone onto hardened superglue and begin scraping with the knife. I had spilled quite a bit of glue onto my Corian countertop so I had to repeat about 4 times. I wiped away the scrapings between each repetition. I've read that you can then sand with 400 grit sandpaper at the end. I can see the need for it and I will finish when I buy the sandpaper. The Corian countertop was not affected at all in this process.

Answer (score 3):

What type of superglue? If it's [CA-based](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyanoacrylate), then this [debonder](http://www.google.com/products/catalog?q=ca+glue+debonder&hl=en&safe=off&prmd=ivsfd&resnum=3&biw=1344&bih=601&um=1&ie=UTF-8&cid=3595332472220379379&ei=FF8FTdPxKsKB8gb7nIjsAg&sa=X&oi=product_catalog_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CEsQ8wIwAA#) will work on it. **I'm not sure how it will do on Corian though.** My guess is that if the glue didn't react with the countertop, then the debonder won't either. (Mostly I've used it for debonding balsa wood and/or carbon fiber.) I'd definitely try it out on a small scale first, and if it doesn't hurt the countertop, then go for it.

[image]

If that doesn't work, then my next plan of action would be scraping it off and buffing.

Comment: Yes, it's a CA glue, I'll give that a shot and update with results.

Answer (score 3):

The debonder is simply acetone.

Comment: @Joe: True, it's usually about 95% acetone. The problem with acetone is that it evaporates very quickly. Most debonders have additives to lower the volatility of the compound to allow it to work on the surface it's applied to before it evaporates. So acetone could be a good first option, and if it doesn't work, then go with a debonder.

Answer (score 1):

Use a new, sharp razor blade and ensure you are parallel to the surface before going in.

Comment: @david i read your update, how'd the razor blade go?